# Want to know startForeground() as user for multiuser

Tags: android, android-notifications, multi-user

I am working on android multi-user. So I have to convert my existing project in to multi user supporting project.

My app will be running in owner. If I switch to user, any related UI actions should be shown on owner or user, 
I am using Context.startActivityAsUser(intent, UserHandle.Current); 
so the activity will be launched on corresponding user or owner.
the same way to launching broadcast events.

In my app, I am using notification as part of service as below 
 startForeground (int id, Notification notification);

as the service is running is owner, the notification is showing on owner only even though I switched to user.
When end user switched to other profile, the notification should be shown on current profile.

as per my knowledge, there is no startForeground(...) as user (i mean as startForegroundAsUser()) so I have converted notification stuff to 
NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(null, appID, notification, UserHandle.CURRENT);
....
When I switch from owner to user, my app is getting crashed and logs also not clear for find the issue. Logcat just says as
 I/ActivityManager(421): Process com.example.test (pid 5833) has died
 W/ActivityManager(421): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.test/com.example.test.testservice in 1000ms
.....
.....
.....

but the service is not started as top profile is CURRENT.

Let me know the other approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cannot do this.  Each app package is installed on the device with a separate data area and process for each human user.  They are purposely kept isolated in memory and filesystem space via Linux UID/GID and permissions.  In Android 5.0 this is further enforced using SE Linux for Android.  So when you are switching (human) users, your apps are being started as separate instances for that person.